# VBS Codes When Writing a File

Tags: vbscript

What do these codes mean?

```
zip.Write Chr(80) & Chr(75) & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, 0)
zip.Write "PK" ^& Chr(5) ^& Chr(6) ^& String(18, vbNullChar)
```

Both make zip file but are different. Does Chr80 and 75 turn out to be PK respectively?

I'm echoing these out of a batch script into a vbs script and running the vbs script. Both seem to be working but the bottom one occasionally gets an error that I can't reproduce.

Comment: Yes, 80 is P and 75 is K

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right. You can use the `Asc()` command to return the character code. So this:

```
WScript.Echo Asc("P") & " " & Asc("K")
```

returns

```
80 75
```

Also, if you want to use the vertical bar, "|", use `Chr("124")`